# Is it possible to limit the depth of dependencies being built by MSBuild?

Tags: c#, build, msbuild

Let's say I have a project 'A', which has a dependency project 'B'. And that project 'B' has 'C' as its dependency. 'C', in turn, has a dependency of 'D', and so on.
Is there any way for the MSBuild command:

`MSBuild Solution.sln /target:A`

to limit the depth of builds to a specific number (let's say not to build dependencies further than 'C', but use dlls in bin/Debug instead)?

Comment: The way MSBuild (basically any build system) works is, that it only rebuilds stuff that
needs a rebuild (because it is out-of-date by some heuristic, mostly write time of
the output). So, once MSBuild has built all your projects - the whole dependency tree - you are basically in the situation where it would only ever rebuild those other projects. MSBuild will always try to build a consistent version of your projects. Thus, it would make little sense to force it to simply "ignore" some changed dependency further down the tree. Sounds like a X/Y problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Christian.K to make story short, I need to run SonarQube analysis on my code. For that, it is mandatory to build the code. But I need just a piece of code to be analyzed. Thus, building the rest is redundant, I just don't need it. So I'm trying to do some "incremental" build, and replace missing dependencies with dlls I already have, but don't need to build.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to 'limit the depth of dependencies' in an MSBuild build.

MSBuild supports incremental builds and a project that is already up-to-date will not be rebuilt. It should be possible to specifically build a project of interest so that all its dependencies are known to be up-to-date, delete the output directory of the project, and then build the project again. Only the project of interest should build.

If (as indicated in the comments) you have an analysis tool that is long running, the above pattern may help. The analysis tool would be turned off on the initial build of the project (which might include dependencies) and turned on for the second build of the project (when all dependencies should be up to date) saving the time of the analysis tool running on projects that are not of interest.

If a given project doesn't seem to be building incrementally, there are some common things to check for including:

- Are there files in the project with 'Copy to Output Directory' set to 'Copy Always'? Change 'Copy Always' to 'Copy if Newer'. Effectively 'Copy Always' means that the project must always be built so that the copy can be performed.
- Are there pre or post build events defined in the Visual Studio C# project properties? Replace with 'native' MSBuild targets. The pre and post build events shell out and MSBuild can't infer any dependencies and will always build the project.

In the bigger picture:

- Small fast full builds are desirable. Large solutions that require incremental builds to be 'useable' should be avoided. Incremental builds over multiple usages can 'drift' and produce incorrect results.
- Use package management tools to break down large solutions. Share at the package level, not the source code level.